# Are questions about the current day off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

If I asked the following question,

> Why did Kabuki [a Japanese performing art] change from predominantly female to predominantly male?

I assume the question would be on-topic under "Cultures and historical practices". But if I were to ask

> Why are most dental hygienists female in present-day United States?

would that be off-topic, because it's about the present day?

Answer (score 6):

That question as presented would probably be off topic.

However, I feel it is readily modifiable to fit History.SE. For example, it could be edited into "When and why did dental hygienists become a predominantly female profession in the United States?"

It is not *precisely* the same question, but I think it would answer a lot of the same questions. And yet, I would argue, it becomes about the *history* of the dental health industry, rather than current-day employment factors and labour statistics.

Comment: This is pretty much my feeling as well. The original question *can* be answered using historical information, but it could also be answered using sociology and psychology with no reference to history at all. Making it clear you want the former keeps things on topic here. If that *isn't* what you want, then yes the question is probably off-topic.

Comment: @Semaphore I generally agree though I think it would still be useful to have a general guideline of say "nothing in the last 10-20 years" as otherwise you are really talking about current statistics and not history per say as otherwise the history of the 2014 stock market its high and its low technically could be 'on topic'.